# How User Story splitting is handled when Version One is integrated with HPALM?

Tags: integration, alm, user-stories, versionone, hp-alm

Our organization is moving towards integrating Version One and HP ALM so that requirements, tests, defects synchronize bidirectionally. Right now we researching on all the possible use cases that we can setup for integration. One of the challenge we are facing is 'User Story Splitting'. If a user story doesn't get completed during a sprint, we split the user story and move the remaining work to next sprint. After integration Version One and HP ALM, how does this synchronization work? How do define that case for integration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which integration approach you chose for this activity. Let me share the challenges we faced during our implementation of similar functionality using Rally.

There is a functionality in Rally by which we are able to split an existing User Story across two iterations/releases. This is generally done for User Stories which were part of one iteration but due to delays or other reasons is being moved to the next iteration. Both entries maintain the efforts at each iteration level. The original user story gets prefixed by “Unfinished” and the new story gets prefixed by “Continued”. There is also a parent user story created for both of these.

This functionality of Rally is however not exposed in its RestAPI interface and no events get triggered or notifications available. The new user story comes in with the add event, but the changes done to the existing with prefix does not flow.

To track the changes done to the older user story we requested user to make manual change in the old story.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what are the integration approaches you are aware of? I am new to this project, we are planning to use a third party integration tool that can expose the objects/fields present in each tool we wanted to integrate, map those entities and define a workflow for the use case.